# How to automatically update a field depending on the user who changed it in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, architecture, django-views

#### Context:

In the Blog part of page any registered User can post, but all posts that are from non superuser accounts have to be approved by an admin on the Admin page where I registered the model as well.
This functions as intended.

#### My question:

How can I make it so that if a Blog Post gets updated by a superuser(doesn't matter what kind of a change for example: when admin opens one single post and adds in a further text in the body of the post, or deletes some part of a text because it seems malicious or fake), that it is automatically approved(The field approved gets then set to TRUE)?
I already thought of adding a further field in the model called changed_by and have it initially null.

#### Code:

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    changed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None) # I am planning to use this but how?

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blogPost-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

blog/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import BlogPost


def approve_multiple_posts(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for blogPost in queryset:
        if blogPost.approved:
            blogPost.approved = False
        else:
            blogPost.approved = True
        blogPost.save()


approve_multiple_posts.short_description = 'Change approval status'


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'author', 'date_posted', 'approved']
    actions = [approve_multiple_posts, ]


admin.site.register(BlogPost, PostAdmin)
```

blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import BlogPost
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)


def blog(request):
    context = {
        'blogPosts': BlogPost.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'
    context_object_name = 'blogPosts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BlogPost.objects.filter(approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'blog/user_blogPosts.html'
    context_object_name = 'blogPosts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return BlogPost.objects.filter(author=user, approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = BlogPost


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            form.instance.approved = True
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = BlogPost
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        blog_post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == blog_post.author:
            return True
        return False


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = BlogPost
    success_url = '/blog'

    def test_func(self):
        blog_post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == blog_post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestions you have! Thanks

Comment: Would the superuser be using the admin, or your `PostUpdateView`?

Comment: The admin. Not the `PostUpdateView` which I wrote @GregKaleka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `PostAdmin` class, you can override a method called `save_model` ([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)). Try something like this:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'author', 'date_posted', 'approved']
    actions = [approve_multiple_posts, ]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        important_fields = ['title', 'content']  # modify save if these fields changed
        if any(x in important_fields for x in form.changed_data):
            obj.approved = request.user.is_superuser
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

This will make `approved` True only if the user is a superuser, otherwise it will be set to False.

Comment: A valid approach ... with a but... I think ```save_model``` is called everytime on saving in the admin, even if no changes have been made to the model. So in order to meet the use case above you need check if the content or title of the ```BlogPost``` instance have changed before setting it to approved.

Comment: Good point @Chris - I edited my answer to check `form.changed_data`.

Comment: Thank you! This has solved my question! But could I ask you to explain this a bit more? Especially the first statement in the if block.

Comment: Sure - the if statement is just a DRY version of `if 'title' in form.changed_data or 'content' in form.changed_data`. Then `obj.approved = request.user.is_superuser` is equivalent to `if request.user.is_superuser: obj.approved = True else: obj.approved = False`. Note that `obj` is the Post object that's being saved. Make sense?